# What is PolkaDot in layman's terms?

Tags: polkadot

So I was trying to dive into the polkadot paper by Gavin Wood, co-founder of Ethereum and founder of Parity. But it seems to be too advanced for my current level of understanding. In layman's terms what exactly is polkadot?

[Here is the link to the paper](http://www.the-blockchain.com/docs/Gavin%20Wood%20-%20Polkadot%20-%20%20Vision%20For%20A%20Heterogeneous%20Multi-chain%20Framework.pdf).

Comment: It would be useful to link to the paper you're referencing, so we can make sure we're answering what you're asking about.

Comment: @AtifAli, is this the paper you are referring to? http://bit.ly/2gIUFtZ

Comment: @MidnightLightning Thanks for the suggestion, will definitely keep that in mind next time! Apologies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Polkadot tries to answer this question: "How do we get blockchains to interact with each other?"

There are quite a number of people online who have tried to introduce PolkaDot in simple terms.  Here are a few summaries I found helpful.

PolkaDot Brings Multiple Blockchains into One Network by Unlocking Scalability and Extensibility -- http://bitcoinprbuzz.com/polkadot-multiple-blockchains-one-network-unlocking-scalability-extensibility/

> Polkadot is a multi-chain framework that supports interoperability
>   between wildly different chains with different properties including
>   encrypted proof-of-authority chains suitable for internal enterprise
>   networks ( – as long as they confirm to certain specifications). For
>   the very first time in blockchain history, the different blockchains
>   will form one large inclusive interoperable multi-chain network with
>   pooled security.

This below is from the Dummies' Guide to PolkaDot and Parachains by Paul Kohlhaas
https://keepingstock.net/a-dummies-guide-to-polkadot-and-parachains-93708bd90775

> Polkadot is a relay mechanism that facilitates authenticated
>   transactions from one blockchain to another... Simply put, Polkadot
>   provides pooled security that is equal to all members, regardless of
>   the protocol they operate on. Second, it enables trust-free
>   transactions between all its member chains. An inter-chain that acts
>   as a pool of secured messaging between blockchains...Polkadot is
>   embarking on a very important and worthwhile research journey into
>   inter-chain operability.

Here is how it is summarized on Github:
https://github.com/polkadot-io/polkadotpaper

> Polkadot allows new designs of blockchains to communicate and pool
>   their security while still allowing them to have entirely arbitrary
>   state-transition functions. This opens to the door to an "internet" of
>   blockchains, where private and consortium chains can be firewalled
>   from open and public chains like Ethereum without losing the ability
>   to communicate with them on their own terms, not unlike the
>   intranet/internet synergy we see today.

There are also several Youtube videos explaining PolkaDot. I found this one really helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfRufqN8S9c&t

An excerpt:

> Polkadot is a network of blockchains that would allow for different
>   blockchains (regardless of their size and functionality or the types
>   of industries and people they catter to) to interact together and to
>   be interoperable, allowing one blockchain to trigger events in another
>   blockchain.

Comment: Tesa, thanks. How do you think, when will we see parachains in action?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good article on the topic. It talks about Polkadot, Cosmos and the differences between them. Everything is broken down into simple concepts. https://perfectial.com/blog/internet-of-blockchains/